# PDF is blank page after converted from html/aspx page using EVOPDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sharepoint-2010, evopdf

Conversion of html/aspx pages into PDF is successful,but PDF file has no actual content in it.

I'm using EVOPDF in sharepoint, Please suggest.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Did you try to display the HTML page you convert in a browser on the same server where you execute the conversion to make sure the HTML page can be loaded well on that server?

Comment: Version (v2.0.50727), I could browse the page url in the server. This is an intermittent issue, Exported PDF file is blank only sometimes. I can see actual content in PDF sometimes.

Comment: That must be the version of the .NET framework. I've been asking about the version of the converter. You can download the latest version from http://www.evopdf.com/download.aspx

Comment: evohtmltopdf, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, I am still facing this issue intermittently. Please suggest any fix.

Comment: we're having the similar issue. After we download the file when opening it in adobe it gives us "Invalid Colorspace" error. We are unsure where the problem lies. We are on MVC5 and use EvoPDF azure implementation. Any help will be appreciated. When opening the file in browser, Chrome for e.g. it is blank.

Comment: I upgraded EVOPDF version 2 to version 6 and tried in test environment, it fixed the issue.                                                                                         
But we need to know the root cause and fix it, instead of upgrading to latest.

Comment: Did you ever identify the problem?